# Defining variables, setters and getters in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a hard time getting myself introduced to Objective-C and iOS programming. I tried to search for this problem, but the results weren't explained simple enough.

So I have a `viewController.h` and a `viewController.m`. In the `.h` I add my Labels/Buttons etc. between `@interface` and `@end`

```
@property ( nonatomic, strong   ) UILabel             *facebookLoginTextLabel;
@property ( nonatomic, strong   ) UIButton            *facebookLoginButton;
```

And in the `.m` I'm simply synthesizing them between `@implementation` and the first method

```
@synthesize facebookLoginTextLabel  = _facebookLoginTextLabel;
@synthesize facebookLoginButton     = _facebookLoginButton;
```

The problem I'm facing now, is what to do with other values? As an example. I have a boolean value. Where do I declare it? How do I set it? How do I get the value? It's way too confusing for me. The same counts for an NSInteger?

I want, dependent on the ifcase, set the `NSInteger` to 0, 1 or 2. How do I achieve this? I tried getting and setting like this

```
.h
@property ( nonatomic ) CGFloat *width;
.m
@synthesize width = _width;

viewDidLoadMethod
_width = [self returnScreenWidth];

returnScreenWith method
- ( CGFloat ) returnScreenWidth {
    return [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
}
```

This doesn't work. Why? How do I set, how do I get? How do I declare variables? Way too confusing from a PHP and an Android-Developer.

Comment: For exammple @property (nonatomic) int simpleIntMember; But instead of using Integers i would use NSNumber in a Objective-C Environment. And you dont have to synthesize them anymore. The Compiler does this automatically for you.

Comment: Setters and getters will be generated for you. You can access via the Dot-Operator or directly call the setter or getter Methods like this : object.simpleIntMember = 10; int b = object.simpleIntMember; int temp =[object getSimpleIntMember]; [object setSimpleIntMember:10]

Comment: Ah! Thank your for this. Should I use a NSNumber for a number or a NSInteger? What's the difference? And why not using int?

Comment: Most of the Objective-C Apis use NSNumbers instead of simple int-type Variables, it is better in Terms of performance and usability cause it is a Object which enables you, for example to convert it back to any format you want: [someNSNumber intValue] or [someNSNumber floatValue]

Comment: You can also simple create a NSNumber from an int like so : NSNumber *yourNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:your_int_variable];

Comment: NSInteger is just a dynamic typedef of int, its size depends on which architecture you are running.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is `CGFloat width` not `CGFloat *width` as it is a C struct, not an Objective C class where you define the property in the header file:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat width;
```

Instead of accessing the under-score instance variable, just use `self.width` whereby you access the `@property` using `self`.

Comment: Oh, I defined all my properties with an `*` before, because I thought that was necessary.

Comment: No, the * is used for references of objects; not C structs. Because C does not define classes or objects, hence, we do not use the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, all **basic/primitive data types** like (int, float, char, BOOL) need not be used as you are doing, always use **`assign`**.

*Yes BOOL is a primitive, as this is typedef to char.*

It should be defined as :

```
@property (assign) <primitivetype> propertyName;
```

Also to note down, with new compiler (I hope you are using Xcode4.2 onwards i.e LLVM),

`@synthesize propertyName` is done automatically by the compiler as

```
@synthesize propertyName = _propertyName;
```

---

`atomic` and `nonatomic` depends on your requirement, so is the pointer to `int` or `float`.